# MongoDB GetAll not returning an object

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I'm trying to GET my entire collection of pokemon from my MongoDB collection.
[My Mongo Collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XN6y1.png)

However, when I'm trying to GET in postman the names aren't being returned. How would I go about having those names be returned?

[My Postman GET for the same object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hozJS.png)

My Current Code:

```
router.get('/getAllPokemon', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const data = await Model.find();
        res.json(data)
    }
    catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({ message: error.message })
    }
})
```

Comment: Did you check your schema for `Model`? Can you post it?

Comment: Yeah can you show your schema and model declarations